# Removing outliers from linear regression when using multiple models

Tags: r, lm

I would like to rerun my multiple linear regression analyses having removed influential observations/outliers to determine their effect. My data has approximately 1000 observations of 30 variables (5 predictors, 25 outcomes).

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(30, sample(0:1000, 1000, rep = TRUE)))
```

I perform multiple linear regression for each of the 25 outcome variables:

```
library(tidyverse)

reg <- df %>%
  gather(outcome_name, outcome_value, -(X1 : X5)) %>%
  group_by(outcome_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(outcome_value ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, data 
  =.)))
```

And then I can subsequently extract the statistics of interest:

```
stats <- reg %>%
  mutate(glance = map(model, broom::glance), 
         tidy = map(model, broom::tidy, conf.int = TRUE)
  )
```

I would like to rerun the above but having removed the outliers either identified, for example, by being > 2 standard deviations above mean, or by identifying them with something like Cook's distance. However, I can't figure out how to exclude the outliers in my code so that each regression model iterates appropriately.

I have tried filtering observations > 2 SD above mean for each outcome variable prior to performing the regression, but I then lost those observations for all 25 outcome regression models, as opposed to the single outcome model for which that observation is an outlier. Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `broom::augment` to add the relevant measures to each dataset, and keep `map`-ping away.

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(replicate(30, sample(0:1000, 1000, rep = TRUE)))

reg <- df %>%
  gather(outcome_name, outcome_value, -(X1 : X5)) %>%
  group_by(outcome_name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(outcome_value ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, data = .)),
         data2 = map(model, augment),
         data3 = map(data2, filter, abs(.std.resid) < 2),
         model2 = map(data3, ~lm(outcome_value ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, data = .)))
```

*Statistician's Disclaimer: I've solved the programming problem you asked. This should not be taken as an endorsement of the idea of automatically checking for, or doing anything with, so-called "outliers".*

Comment: I like the disclaimer. +1

Comment: @ngm Thank you for that tidy solution. I had completely overlooked the `augment` function when coding my original analysis a few months back. Disclaimer duly noted.